# schedule a monthly DAG to run on the next weekday

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have to schedule a DAG that should run on 15th of every month. However, if 15th falls on a Sunday/Saturday then the DAG should skip weekends and run on coming Monday.

For example, May 15 2021 falls on a Saturday. So, instead of running on 15th of May, the DAG should run on 17th, which is Monday.

Can you please help to schedule it in airflow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Airflow >= 2.2.0:**

Airflow [AIP-39 Richer scheduler_interval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval) has been completed. This allows more scheduling capabilities. You can use [Timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timetable.html) feature for that. This will allow you to customize scheduling time according to your needs. Either use a build-in timetable or create one of yours.

**For Airflow < 2.2.0:**

The logic of scheduling is limited by what you can do with single cron expression. So if you can't say it in cron expression you can't provide such scheduling in Airflow.

That said, you can still get the desired functionality by writing some code.
You can set your dag to start on the 15th of each month and then place a sensor that verify that the date is Mon-Fri (if not it will wait):

```
from airflow.sensors.weekday import DayOfWeekSensor
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='work',
    schedule_interval='0 0 15 * *',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Schedule a Job on 15 of each month',
)

weekend_check = DayOfWeekSensor(
    task_id='weekday_check_task',
    week_day={'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'},
    mode='reschedule',
    dag=dag)

op_1 = YourOperator(task_id='op1_task',dag=dag)

weekend_check >> op_1
```

Note: If you are running `airflow<2.0.0` you will need to change the import to:

```
from airflow.contrib.sensors.weekday_sensor import DayOfWeekSensor
```

Comment: this is a smart working solution. Thanks for taking out time to address my questions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Elad works pretty well. I came up with another solution that works as well.

I scheduled the job to run on 15,16 and 17 of the month. However, I added a condition so that the job runs on the 15th if its a weekday. The job runs on 16th and 17th if its a Monday.

To achieve that, I added a BranchPythonOperator:

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator

def _conditinal_task_initiator(**kwargs):
execution_date=kwargs['execution_date']
if int(datetime.strftime(execution_date,'%d'))==15 and (execution_date.weekday()<5):
    return 'dummy_task_run_cmo_longit'
elif int(datetime.strftime(execution_date,'%d'))==16 and (execution_date.weekday()==0):
    return 'dummy_task_run_cmo_longit'
elif int(datetime.strftime(execution_date,'%d'))==17 and (execution_date.weekday()==0):
    return 'dummy_task_run_cmo_longit'
else:
    return 'dummy_task_skip_cmo_longit'

with DAG(dag_id='NXS_FM_LOAD_CMO_CHOICE_LONGIT',default_args = default_args, schedule_interval = "0 8 15-17 * *", catchup=False) as dag:
conditinal_task_initiator=BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='cond_task_check_day',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=_conditinal_task_initiator,
    do_xcom_push=False)
dummy_task_run_cmo_longit=DummyOperator(
    task_id='dummy_task_run_cmo_longit')
dummy_task_skip_cmo_longit=DummyOperator(
    task_id='dummy_task_skip_cmo_longit')

conditinal_task_initiator >> [dummy_task_run_cmo_longit,dummy_task_skip_cmo_longit]

dummy_task_run_cmo_longit >> <main tasks for execution>
```

Using this, the job'll run on 15,16 and 17 of every month. However, it'll run the functional tasks only once every month.

Comment: You may want to look at BranchDayOfWeekOperator that I recently added : https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13997

Comment: @Elad, I am using apache airflow 1.10.12. The BranchDayOfWeekOperator is not present in this version. Looks like this class will solve my problem more elegantly.

Comment: You can always copy the operator to your code and use it. If and when you will upgrade you can remove the code and replace it with import from airflow core. I'm only suggesting an option.